# Why is mysql slow?

Tags: mysql

```
# at 198534220
#180227 14:18:11 server id 25  end_log_pos 198534292    Query   thread_id=1059867       exec_time=3     error_c
ode=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1519708691/*!*/;
SET @@session.pseudo_thread_id=1059867/*!*/;
SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=1, @@session.sql_auto_is_null=0, @@session.unique_checks=1, @@session.autocomm
it=1/*!*/;
SET @@session.sql_mode=0/*!*/;
SET @@session.auto_increment_increment=1, @@session.auto_increment_offset=1/*!*/;
/*!\C utf8 *//*!*/;
SET @@session.character_set_client=33,@@session.collation_connection=33,@@session.collation_server=8/*!*/;
SET @@session.lc_time_names=0/*!*/;
SET @@session.collation_database=DEFAULT/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
```

There is a delay in replication.

I checked mysql bin log.
But I do not know why that is slow.

What can I check?

Answer (score 0):

what you asking it look like you need to tune your database. This is a complex process.

If you have a script that runs lots of SQL and slows down your DB, and your cpu and memory usage are fine while it's running, then you are probably running into I/O problems. You need to look through the SQL used in the script and tune it. It might be generating lots of full table scans or creating too many transaction logs that are slowing down the DB.

You can search for tuning of databases.